# How to find the average of the cosecutive specified rows in a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to find the average of every 100 rows consecutively in 2 million rows and save these 2000 values in a new column.

Can any one help me either by a VBA or by a Formula in Excel 2007.

waiting for the reply.

Comment: Did you mean `200,000` rows? Excel's row limit is `1,048,576` rows. :) Also, kindly show us if you've tried anything. A simple formula would do here, really. :)

Comment: I tried with the simple average formula to find the average of the first 100 data points(C1:C100) and coped it down but, the next average value corresponds to (C2:C101). what i want is (C101:C200) as the next average value. And 2,00,000 is less than 10,48,576. So i think it can work in excel. Can you help me.

Comment: Oh man... Excel's limit is 1.04 million rows, which is a little above half of 2 million. Maybe you mean 200,000 rows? Because you specified 2,000,000 above. Also, what you're doing is correct, actually. You're just approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: ohh sorry for the miss communication. i mean 200,000 only. i will try again.thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Okay, now that we have that pat down, see how I'll approach it with formulas only. Posting an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to set-it up correctly. With the proper set-up, this is a cinch, really. VBA is just going to make this a wee bit easier, but native formulas can do just as well.

Assume I have values in `A1:A1000`. `A1` has 1, `A2` has 2, etc. You get the point. Eventually, `A1000` has 1000.

Now, copy the following set-up for the specified cells:

- `B1`: 1
- `C1`: 100
- `B2`: `=C1+1`
- `C2`: `=C1+100`

Drag down to `B10:C10`.

Now, input the following formula to `D1`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&C1))
```

Drag down to `D10`. Voila. You have the average of each 100-row cluster.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A single formula:

```
=INT((ROW()-2)/100)
```

in say B2 and copied down (to group in hundreds) and a PivotTable with the ColumnB label as Row Labels and Average of the value label in Σ Values is quite straightforward.

If the banding is required, change the formula for `=ROW()-1` and Group in the PT.